# Avoid loading XAML each time when ApplyTemplate()

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I'm working on performance improvement for a WPF grid and find out the `ApplyTemplate()` calls for cells consume quite some resources. Each time we create a cell and apply the `ControlTemplate` to it, it loads the XAML again, although I think this should be cached for the same template.

[image: Profiling result]

Is that possible to save the cost from loading XMAL again and again?

Also, is it possible to build a `ControlTemplate` which doesn't rely on the XAML, but we could programmatically set up the visual tree to improve the performance?

**Update:**

I've tried to use the template created by code and generated the visual tree completely by `FrameworkElementFactory`. The profiling result shows we don't have performance gains by this approach.

[image: Profiling result with FrameworkElementFactory]

It seems that the XAML parsing in each `ApplyTemplate` call doesn't cost much, but the visual tree instantiation take most of the time.

Comment: Have you tried setting Virtualization with VirtualizationMode set to Recycle the template?

Comment: @ChrisW. Virtualization is enabled, but we still need to create 1200 cells to fill the display area in the grid.

Comment: Right, so that's where [VirtualizationMode=Recycling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizationmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) comes in instead of Standard, at least that's what I took from "it loads the XAML again, although I think this should be cached for the same template." so then you would be reusing the same container

Comment: @ChrisW.: Sorry, I don't quite get what you suggested. The template is required to be applied to each cell for sure (let's consider that the first time we bind items to the grid and 1200 new cells are created), how does `VirtualizationMode` affect here? I don't want the template to load XAML each time it's applied to the cell.

Comment: It just uses the same template for each instance instead of creating new objects in the tree, you can read up on how Recycling works around the net.

Comment: The `VirtualizationMode` is already `Recycling` during the test.

Comment: @JeffreyZhao Have you finally found a solution for this problem?